# Obstacle random gap not working [SpriteKit] [Swift]

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a problem in my code. When I run the game, I have two obstacles (one on the left and one on the right). I coded a gap between each obstacle and it has been working. I have a problem where the gap sometimes spawns off of the screen where the player cannot get to. How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
let gapWidth = square.size.width * 1.5
    var movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.width/2)
    var obstacleOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) -  self.frame.size.width / 2

    var obstacle1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Obstacle")
    obstacle1.zPosition = 30
    obstacle1.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 300)
    obstacle1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + obstacle1.size.width / 2 + gapWidth / 2 + obstacleOffset, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(obstacle1)

    var obstacle2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Obstacle")
    obstacle2.zPosition = 30
    obstacle2.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 300)
    obstacle2.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - obstacle2.size.width / 2 - gapWidth / 2 + obstacleOffset, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(obstacle2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the values of the random positions will always be on the screen. You can do that by using code similar to this:

```
var height = UInt32(self.frame.size.height)
var randomYPos = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(height)))
```

You can do the same for the random x value, just use the screen width. You only need to do this for obstacle 1, then set the position of obstacle 2 relative to obstacle 1.